# android 4.3 Bluetooth ble don't called onCharacteristicRead()

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, android-notifications

I've set the notification into android, It is not calling to method `onCharacteristicRead()`????
It does not enter into the function. Why it is happening so??

Any help is appreciated

Request the solutions.

**This is my code:**

```
private final BluetoothGattCallback mGattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status,
            int newState) {
        if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Connected to GATT server.");
            // Attempts to discover services after successful connection.
            Log.i(TAG, "Attempting to start service discovery:"
                    + mBluetoothGatt.discoverServices());
        } else if (newState == BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Disconnected from GATT server.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            gattServices = mBluetoothGatt
                    .getService(SampleGattAttributes.SERVICES_UUID);
            if (gattServices != null) {
                gattCharacteristics = gattServices
                        .getCharacteristic(SampleGattAttributes.CHARACTERISTIC_UUID);
                System.out.println("character-->" + gattCharacteristics);
            }
            if (gattCharacteristics != null) {
                System.out.println("Characteristic not null");
                System.out.println("Characteristic Properties-->"
                        + gattCharacteristics.getProperties());
                mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(gattCharacteristics,
                true);
            }
        } else {
            Log.w(TAG, "onServicesDiscovered received: " + status);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic, int status) {
        System.out.println("in read");
        if (status == BluetoothGatt.GATT_SUCCESS) {
            byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
            System.out.println("reading");
            System.out.println(new String(data));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onCharacteristicChanged(BluetoothGatt gatt,
            BluetoothGattCharacteristic characteristic) {
        //
        System.out.println("change");
        byte[] data = characteristic.getValue();
        System.out.println(new String(data));
    }
};
```

Thank you in advance!!

Answer (score 26, accepted):

First of all `onCharacteristicRead` will fire if you have read a characteristic by:

```
 mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);
```

Reading a characteristic and setting up notifications are two different things. What is the type of your characteristic you want to get data from?

Is it:

- read
- notify
- indicate

If it is `read` you can read the characteristic using the `mBluetoothGatt.readCharacteristic(characteristic);` method but if its `notify` or `indicate` first you will have to read the characteristic's `descriptor` by calling:

```
mBluetoothGatt.readDescriptor(ccc);
```

Once you read it, it should return data by calling the `onDescriptorRead` callback.
Here you can set up (subscribe) to the charactersitic through either notification or indication by calling:

```
mBluetoothGatt.setCharacteristicNotification(characteristic, true)
```

once it returns `true` you will need to write to the descriptor again (the value of notification or indication)

```
BluetoothGattDescriptor clientConfig = characteristic.getDescriptor(CCC);
clientConfig.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);
// or
//clientConfig.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_INDICATION_VALUE);
mBluetoothGatt.writeDescriptor(clientConfig);
```

Once this is done you will get notifications throuhg `onCharacteristicChanged` callback every time the characteristic changes.

you can read more about Bluetooth connection on Android [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html)
and about Bluetooth Characteristics [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGattCharacteristic.html)

Comment: THanks for the Answer.I have lost the Descriptor and set the wrong uuid ,so the Descriptor is null ,it don't execute the clientConfig.setValue(BluetoothGattDescriptor.ENABLE_NOTIFICATION_VALUE);

Comment: Hello benka i am facing problem while read and write operation will you help me out.

Comment: @chet's - post the link to your question and let me see if i can do anything for you.

Comment: @benka please check my question on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27443139/android-4-3-bluetooth-ble-dont-called-oncharacteristicread-after-write-operat