# BLE - ReadCharacteristic return false

Tags: c#, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm trying to read a characteristic with `ReadCharacteristic()`.

But the function always return false.

What I have checked :

- the UUID is the right one.
- the connection is stable.
- the UUID is readable.
- there is no other call of `ReadCharacteristic()` -> `OnCharacteristicRead` is never called

Many topics, such as this one:

[android 4.3 Bluetooth ble don't called onCharacteristicRead()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25865587/android-4-3-bluetooth-ble-dont-called-oncharacteristicread)

suggests that it's not necessary to do others things in order to receive the data.

Do I need to do additionnal things to make it work ? (like operations on descriptors?)

[open to any grammar/ortographic edit]

Comment: What about manifest permissions? Do you have all required ones?

Comment: My permissions related to bluetooth are: BLUETOOTH, BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, BLUETOOTH_PRIVILEGED. As I'm under Marshmallow, I also ask them at runtime.

Comment: See the method "readCharacteristic" at https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/bluetooth/BluetoothGatt.java. There you have all reasons why it may return false. In particular, you can not have more than one outstanding GATT operation at a time (you need to wait for callback before you can issue a new one).

Comment: Everything was fine in the code, that was a firmware issue. Thanks for help.

Comment: @Greg can you give little bit brieff about how you sloved because i'm also facing same issue .

Comment: @YBDevi it's quite old but as far as I remember, it was a firmware issue. The bluetooth device was a prototype, and there was an error in the documentation of it's UUIDs leading us to believe it was an issue on the C# app. You should also check your permissions as stated in the comments

Comment: @Greg for my BLE device there is properties,i have checked those are READ only still those methods are not calling.